# If a topological space $X$ has open path connected components and is connected then $X$ is path connected

Tags: general-topology

Why does it hold?

I know that connected, locally path connected topological spaces are path-connected. Is it an equivalence statement?

Comment: Any connected topological space is trivially an open connected component of itself.

Comment: Sorrry about that. It is open path connected components

Comment: Usually, locally path-connected means the stronger condition that every point has a fundamental system of (open?) path-connected neighbourhoods. In fact, there are topological spaces which are path connected but not locally path-connected, namely $\{(x,y)\in\Bbb R^2\,:\, y=0\lor x\in\Bbb Q\}$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The path connected components of $X$ give a partition $\left\{C_i:i\in I\right\}$ of $X$. By hypothesis, all $C_i$ are open, so all $C_i=X\setminus\bigcup_{j\neq i}C_i$ are also closed.

Taking any $C_i$, it is a nonempty clopen set, so $X=C_i$ by connectedness.

Answer (score 0):

Let $X = \bigcup_{i \in I} U_i$ be the path components of $X$. By hypothesis, the $U_i$ are open. Furthermore, path components are disjoint, as they are equivalence classes under the relation $x \sim y$ if $x$ and $y$ can be joined by a path. Hence, the above is a disjoint union of open subsets of $X$. As $X$ is connected, this can only occur for $|I|=1$, i.e. if $X$ equals some path component. Thus, $X$ is path connected.